# Porque no encuentra a mi controlador?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo un error al clickear en un link y que me redirija a una vista con un metodo add.

El error que obtengo es este:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Presupuesto] does not exist.
```

Este es mi metodo add de Presupuesto controller:

```
public function add(){
        $presupuesto['formasDePagos'] = Ptype::all();        
        $presupuesto['estadoPresupuestos'] = ModelP::all();
        return view('backend.presupuesto.add-presupuesto', $presupuesto);
    }
```

Estos son los namespace y modelos que estoy utilizando en Presupuesto controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Presupuesto;
use App\Model\EstadoPresupuesto;
use App\Model\FormaDePago;
use Auth;
use Session;
```

Mis rutas en web.php:

```
Route::prefix('presupuestos')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/view','Backend\PresupuestoController@view')->name('presupuestos.view');
        Route::get('/add','Backend\Presupuesto@add')->name('presupuestos.add');
        Route::post('/store','Backend\Presupuesto@store')->name('presupuestos.store');
    });
```

Y este es el boton/link que me lleva al error:

```
<h3 class="font-weight-light text-white">Presupuestos
                                <a class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm" href="{{ route('presupuestos.add') }}"><i
                                        class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Presupuesto</a>
                            </h3>
```

Alguien sabe porque obtengo este error y logra identificar en que parte de mi código lo tengo? Porque nunca obtuve un error de este tipo.

Answer (score 3):

Verifica que el nombre de tu clase de controlador es correcta, si te das cuenta en tu código

```
Route::get('/view','Backend\PresupuestoController@view')->name('presupuestos.view');
    Route::get('/add','Backend\Presupuesto@add')->name('presupuestos.add');
```

en la segunda linea solo esta Presupuesto y en la primera PresupuestoController